# Write table output into a single line

Tags: r

I read a table into R with `read.table` it looks like

```
     V1
[1,] "POS"
[2,] "38500002"
[3,] "38500010"
[4,] "38500069"
[5,] "38500145"
[6,] "38500187"
```

I need to write it to a file, but all in a single line:

`"POS" "38500002" "385000010" ...`

How could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - please post a sample of you data file and the code you used to read it so that people can help you

Answer (score 2):

The data you show is likely not the immediate result of `read.table` since read.table creates a `data.frame` and what you show is a `matrix` (judging from the row names).

Either way, if it's a single column you can use `write.table` on the *transposed* data, since transposing will coerce the data to matrix form anyway.  If you wish to write it to file, use the `file` argument.

```
## read in the data
> dat <- read.table(h=T, text = 'V1
 "POS"
 "38500002"
 "38500010"
 "38500069"
 "38500145"
 "38500187"')

> write.table(t(dat), col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
## "POS" "38500002" "38500010" "38500069" "38500145" "38500187"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data.frame

```
df<-data.frame(V1=c("POS","38500002","38500010","38500069", "38500145", "38500187"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And you want to write out those values with quotes, then

```
cat(paste("\"", df$V1, "\"", collapse=" ", sep=""), file="myfile.txt")
```

should do just fine. I used `paste` to get all the quote around the terms. YOu have to escape the quote to get to print. And then `cat` allows you to send the output directly to a file